# Complex SQL aggregation

Tags: t-sql, aggregation

I have a dataset that analogously looks like this:

```
X | U | datetime
-------------
1 | 1 | 1/1/12
1 | 2 | 1/1/12
1 | 2 | 1/1/12
1 | 2 | 1/1/12
1 | 4 | 1/1/12
2 | 2 | 2/1/12
2 | 3 | 2/1/12
1 | 3 | 3/1/12
2 | 4 | 3/1/12
3 | 2 | 4/1/12
```

it is a log of visits. `X` is the id of the thing visited, and `U` is the user id

I need to compute two statistics.

Given a value for X (x):

1. "new visitors": count the number of unique users that made their first visit for any X to `x`.

use cases:

- A user has only visited `x` once -> counts as 1
- A user has only visited `!x` once -> counts as 0
- A user has only visited `x` twice -> counts as 1
- A user has only visited `!x` twice -> counts as 0
- A user has visited many Xs, where their first visit of any X is `x` -> counts as 1
- A user has visited many Xs, where their first visit of any X is `!x` -> counts as 0

Examples from above data:

```
X | Count
---------
1 | 3
2 | 1
3 | 0
```

2. "returning visitors": count the number of unique users that have visited `x` more than once OR have visited `x` once, but have visited another X previously (i.e. visits made after their single visit to `x` do not count)

Examples from above data:

```
X | Count
---------
1 | 3
2 | 2
3 | 1
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

### Update

This appears to answer Q1, although it's not very fast :(

```
select x.X, COUNT(1)
from (
    select t1.X
    from @t t1
    group by t1.X, t1.U
    having (select COUNT (1) from @t t2 where t2.u= t1.U and t2.OccurredOn < MIN(t1.OccurredOn)) =0 
) x 
group by x.X
```

**Update 2**

I *think* this is (2)

```
select t.X, COUNT(1)
from @t t
left join (
    select t.U, MIN(t.OccurredOn) as O
    from @t t
    group by t.U
) x on t.U = x.U and t.OccurredOn <= x.O
where x.U is null
group by t.X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, you need a sub-query to join to that will filter out all user-thing visits that aren't the first of their kind. So you'll have something like

```
select X, count(*) [First Visits]
from table t1
     join (select U, min(datetime) firstvisit 
           from table 
           group by U) t2 on t1.datetime = t2.firstvisit and t1.U = t2.U
group by X
```

Edit: I think your solution to the second one is fine, except that the join will be faster if you replace the `<=` with simply `=`.

Comment: sorry, i accidentally forgot the other parts of the join for the first one. should work.

Comment: yeah i spotted that and added them in, it still isnt right. Its not excluding users who have previously made a visit to a different X

Comment: ah i see i was confused by your example. your short description and the longer "use cases" description seem at odds. how could the sum of "new users" be greater than the distinct count of those users?

Comment: my update to #1 gives the same output as your update. neither of these gives the same result as your sample answer...

Comment: hmm what was confusing you? it reads ok to me, whats the mistake, don't want to be confusing either of us :) Yes, your (1) does agree with mine, and is considerably faster. Now onto (2)!